# Cordova and iOS: how to load plugins?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, ripple

I built a smartphone application with Visual Studio 2015 and Cordova (6.1.1) on a windows 10 pro pc. It runs great on Android (simulator and device).

When I try to run it in debug-mode on iOS (Ripple iphone 4 and 5) I get errors – **"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404"**.

I'm getting these errors for all plugins, and specifically for File and FileTransfer.

How can I fix this?

Tnx.

Comment: Could you test it on Android(Ripple)?

Comment: @George Could you post the file transfer code that is failing? Could be a possible transport security issue. Try adding this plugin and try once - https://github.com/robertklein/cordova-ios-security

Comment: yes. all plugins were loaded on android. on IOS no plugin was loaded.

Comment: _this.$rootScope.fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

Comment: Ripple doesn't provide simulation of capabilities(plugins) see first "caution" of [this link](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/run-app-ripple-simulator/). If you want to test your app with plugins on ios the [remote build process](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/ios-guide/) is necessary.

Comment: sorry for a late response. I installed the app on MacInCloud, and tested it with the iphone 4s simulator and local device. The cordova-plugin-file, and cordova-plugin-file-transfer were not found. The app ran until it reached the point of using theses plugins.

Comment: what error message did you get?

Comment: cordova.file: undefined (cordova exists). new FileTransfer():" Can't find variable: FileTransfer".

Comment: Could you try it on a new blank app?

Comment: tried a blank app with iphone 4s simulator. the file plugin was found, but the file transfer issued the same message: "Can't find ..."

Comment: correction: the message when trying to instance FileTransfer: "FileTransfer is not defined".

Comment: Could you try reinstalling the plugin. If the problem persists, could you share a sample please.

Comment: yes, the problem persists. Within the deviceReady listener:

Comment: try {
                var data = cordova.file.dataDirectory;
                console.log(cordova.file.dataDirectory);
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(data, function (fs) { });
                alert('file success:' + data);
            } catch (err) {
                alert('file: ' + err.message);
            }
            try {
                console.log(FileTransfer);
                var fileTransfer = new FileTranser();
                alert('ft success');
            } catch (err) {
                alert('ft: ' + err.message);
            }

Comment: I ready to share the whole sample app, but how?

Comment: You can post the sample to a repository of [GitHub](https://github.com/). And post the link of the sample. And `new FileTranser()` is misspelled. Should be `new FileTransfer()`.